# PostgreSQL aggregate and avg on colum value bias

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know if it's possible in psql to obtain a set of row that match this criteria

table 
      
1/0         23      timestamp without timezone

let's imagine a set of data

```
1  12 2014-07-14 09:01:00
1  13 2014-07-14 09:02:00
1  14 2014-07-14 09:03:00
1  15 2014-07-14 09:04:00
0  16 2014-07-14 09:05:00
0  17 2014-07-14 09:06:00
0  18 2014-07-14 09:07:00
1  17 2014-07-14 09:08:00
1  16 2014-07-14 09:09:00
```

I would like to retrive the data group by status, but keeping the date order and status change.

i.e.:

```
1 <avg temp> <avg date> (calculated over the first 4 rows)
0 <avg temp> <avg date> (calculated for the 3 rows with 0)
1 <avg temp> <avg date> (calculated for the last 2 rows)
```

Basically 1/0 means that the heater is on/off, and I would like to 
calculate the AVG temp but grouped by status of this heater

p.s.:

Obviously a simple select avg(temp),status from log group by status
will not make the trick, it will only return 1/0 values, not the range and the change between on/off

Another case that will be great to handle is leave the 1st record of each status change untouched.

ie:

```
1 <temp> <date> (calculated over the first)
1 <avg temp> <avg date> (calculated over the first 3 rows)
0 <temp> <date> (for the row 4)
0 <avg temp> <avg date> (from 5 to 6)
1 <temp> <date> (row 7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  Here is an approach using window functions.  It generates a flag to see if one row's status differs from the previous and then does a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*, sum(statuschange) over (order by date) as grp
from (select t.*,
             (case when lag(status) over (order by date) <> status then 1
                   else 0
              end) as statuschange
      from table t
     ) t;
```

The rest is just grouping on this field:

```
select status, avg(temp), min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*, sum(statuschange) over (order by date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when lag(status) over (order by date) <> status then 1
                         else 0
                    end) as statuschange
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp, status;
```

I'm not sure the best way to do an average of a date in Postgres, so this includes the minimum and maximum.  Your problem seems to be more about defining the groups than getting the average of the date/time column.

Comment: intresting, that's exactly what i was looking for, now to complicate it a little bit more, it's possible to do the same thing leaving the 1st sample of each 'change' untouched? more info on edit the question

Comment: @user3804873 . . . Changing the question after it has been answered is generally impolite.  I'm not sure what you mean by leaving a sample "untouched".  If you don't want to include it, that is possible by including a `where statuschange = 0` in the middle subquery.

Comment: sorry, i am still new on stackoverflow!